# Show fullscreen image onTap in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have image shown using one of Flutter widgets

```
Image.network(....);
```

I want to add functionality that after tapping on image I can present this image in fullscreen mode. How it can be done?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You say you want something like in this [flutter cookbook](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/hero-animations)?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(HeroApp());

class HeroApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Image/Detail Demo',
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Main Screen'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'imageHero',
          child: Image.network(
            'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/src/_includes/code/layout/lakes/images/lake.jpg',
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
            return DetailScreen();
          }));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Center(
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'imageHero',
            child: Image.network(
              'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/src/_includes/code/layout/lakes/images/lake.jpg',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use the [cache_network_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image) package to show the cached image without download it again.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

void main() => runApp(HeroApp());

class HeroApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Image/Detail Demo',
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Main Screen'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'imageHero',
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl:  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/src/_includes/code/layout/lakes/images/lake.jpg',
            placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
          )
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
            return DetailScreen();
          }));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Center(
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'imageHero',
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl:  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/src/_includes/code/layout/lakes/images/lake.jpg',
              placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
              errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**My final release (with real fullscreen):**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(HeroApp());

class HeroApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Image/Detail Demo',
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Main Screen'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Hero(
            tag: 'imageHero',
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl:
                  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/src/_includes/code/layout/lakes/images/lake.jpg',
              placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
              errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
            )),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
            return DetailScreen();
          }));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
  @override
  initState() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Center(
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'imageHero',
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl:
                  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/src/_includes/code/layout/lakes/images/lake.jpg',
              placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
              errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Passing data from main to detail page**

Just to complete my answer, I add some code showing how you could pass the image url from main to detail page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(HeroApp());

class HeroApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Image/Detail Demo',
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  var _url = [
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/src/_includes/code/layout/lakes/images/lake.jpg',
    'https://github.com/flutter/plugins/raw/master/packages/video_player/doc/demo_ipod.gif?raw=true'
  ];
  var _tag = ['imageHero', 'imageHero2'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Main Screen'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            child: Hero(
                tag: _tag[0],
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: _url[0],
                  placeholder: Center(child: Container(width: 32, height: 32,child: new CircularProgressIndicator())),
                  errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
                )),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return DetailScreen(tag: _tag[0], url: _url[0]);
              }));
            },
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            child: Hero(
                tag: _tag[1],
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: _url[1],
                  placeholder: Center(child: Container(width: 32, height: 32,child: new CircularProgressIndicator())),
                  errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
                )),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return DetailScreen(tag: _tag[1], url: _url[1]);
              }));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String tag;
  final String url;

  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.tag, @required this.url})
      : assert(tag != null),
        assert(url != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
  @override
  initState() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Center(
          child: Hero(
            tag: widget.tag,
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: widget.url,
              placeholder: Center(child: Container(width: 32, height: 32,child: new CircularProgressIndicator())),
              errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In order to pop back tapping outside the image, bring outside the `GestureDetector` in the `Detail` widget.

```
class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
  @override
  initState() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Scaffold (
        body: Center(
          child: Hero(
            tag: widget.tag,
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: widget.url,
              placeholder: Center(child: Container(width: 32, height: 32,child: new CircularProgressIndicator())),
              errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this solution works but when I tap outside the presented image I am not returning to previous page, any ideas how it can be solved?

Comment: @moonvader so in the detail page switch `GestureDetector` and `Scaffold`. See update ^_^

Comment: For anyone with version 0.7.0 or later: `placeholder: (context, url) =>` and `errorWidget: (context, url, error) => `

Comment: @alex351 yep there have been **breaking changes** in `CacheNetworkImage` from version [0.6.0](https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image/tree/v0.6.1) and later. Thanks to point this out!

Answer (score 8):

You can easily use this package  [easy_image_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_image_viewer)

It worked perfectly without having to create a new screen to handle full screen.
The package handles full screen, pinching, zooming in and out of image.
Check this sample code below.

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            showImageViewer(context, Image.asset("asset/image/myimage.jpg").image,
                swipeDismissible: false);
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 150,
            child: Image.asset(
             "asset/image/myimage.jpg",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        )
```

The Image opens in full screen, pinchable and zoomable.

Comment: This package is a real time saver !

Comment: A lot of developers don't know this yet

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code to have full screen of image!

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'imageHero',
            child: Image.network(
              'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No arash no. youre missing a large piece of code that is needed to be included with this. Edit it and fix it or delete

Comment: This is just a piece of an answer...

Answer (score 2):

I simply found a library with just about what you are looking for and with animated Hero effects.
[full_screen_image](https://pub.dev/packages/full_screen_image) by furkan.kayali@bil.omu.edu.tr

```
FullScreenWidget(
    child: Hero(
      tag: "customTag",
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/image2.jpg",
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `easy_image_viewer` package. [view](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_image_viewer/install)

**This example for Network image**,

This package provides an easy-to-use and highly customizable image viewer. It allows you to display images in a full-screen view with zooming, panning, and rotation capabilities.

@Amfstacks shows how this works for image which is in your assets. This example for Network image,

```
        GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  final imageProvider =
                      Image.network("your url").image;
                  showImageViewer(context, imageProvider,
                      onViewerDismissed: () {
                    print("dismissed");
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    child: Image(
                      image: NetworkImage("your url"),
                    )),
              ),
```